# Residues of $\frac{1}{1-az} e^{-\frac{i t}{2}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have been fighting with a contour integral with the following integrand

\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{1-az} e^{-\frac{i t}{2}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)}
\end{align*}
for $a,t>0$ real constants. I think this has a simple pole at $z=a^{-1}$ and two essential essential singularities at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$. I find the residue for the simple pole to be
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=a^{-1}\right) = -\frac{1}{a} e^{-\frac{i t}{2}\left(a+a^{-1}\right)}
\end{align*}
For the essential singularity at $z=0$, I use the Laurent series
\begin{align*}
e^{-\frac{i t}{2}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)} = \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} z^n I_{n}(-it) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(z^n +\frac{1}{z^n}\right) I_{n}(-it) - I_{0}(-it)
\end{align*}
Where in the second equality I used $I_{-n}(t)=I_{n}(t)$ and subtracted the double counting. Similarly, around $z=0$ I use
\begin{align*}
(1-az)^{-1} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n z^n 
\end{align*}
And so,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-az} e^{-\frac{i t}{2}\left(z+z^{-1}\right)} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(z^{2n-k}+z^{-k}\right) a^{n-k}I_{n}(-it) -I_{0}(-it)\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n z^n 
\end{align*}
And the term with power $z^{-1}$ comes from $k=1$,
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n-1}I_{n}(-it) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{n-1}I_{n}(-it)
\end{align*}
Is this sensible? I am unsure about the convergence and about the product of the series. In the neighbourhood of $\infty$, the Laurent series of the exponential remains the same (symmetry under $z\to z^{-1}$), while $(1-ax)^{-1} = -\sum (a z)^{-(n+1)}$?

Comment: You can also try making a change of variables with $2w = z+z^{-1}$ when integrating around a small circle centered at the origin.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, thank you for the suggestion. Actually this transformation takes me back to my original integral which is the Fourier Transform of a function that has some branch cuts. I was trying to avoid them, but I am not sure it makes life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. In a punctured neighbourhood of $z=0$ we have

$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{1-az}e^{\frac{it}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)}=\sum_{l\geq 0}a^l z^l \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{it}{2}\right)^m z^m \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{it}{2}\right)^n \frac{1}{z^n}$$
hence
$$ \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right) = \sum_{l\geq 0}a^l\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!}\left(\frac{it}{2}\right)^m\frac{1}{(m+l+1)!}\left(\frac{it}{2}\right)^{l+m+1}$$
can be written as
$$ \sum_{l\geq 0}a^l i^{l+1} J_{l+1}(t) $$
with $J_{l+1}$ being a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). $J_{l+1}(t)$ is rapidly decreasing to zero as $l\to +\infty$, hence the previous series is absolutely convergent for any $a$. The residue at infinity can be computed in a similar way, by expanding $\frac{1}{1-az}$ as mentioned.